# File upload and download on Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I want have my azure . NET web application upload a file, manipulate it and then download the changed version.

Should I use blob storage? I don't actually need to store the data in the file.

Comment: Blob storage (just like any other storage) is meant to use when you *do* need to store the data, if you *do not* need to store the data and able to manipulate it on the fly (from memory stream probably) then don't store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use blob storage?

That depends on what your requirements are.

> I don't actually need to store the data in the file.

Given this fact, you probably don't need to use blog storage.

You could simply do something like this:

```
var postedFile = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;
var stream = new MemoryStream();
postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
// work with MemoryStream
...
//return your file which could be different based on mvc, web forms or whatever
```